# How to access elements in the table cell

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTML table to traverse using DOM. 
I begin accessing using my table id and then I am able to access a particular cell.

```
'<td><a onclick=send_symbol_2(\"'+comp+'\")>'+comp+'</a></td>'
```

I am confused on how to access the data contained within anchor tags. I had earlier constructed the table by adding strings. 
eg: `'<tr></td><td>'+arr[4]+'</td></tr>'`
I understand toString() would been called. 
I am unsure how to proceed further. 
I used

```
rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]
```

to access the cell data.

Comment: `rows[i].querySelector('a')`. Incidentally, given a reference to a row `rows[i]` you can get the cells with `rows[i].cells`, you don't need to call `.getElementsByTagName("td")`. So `rows[i].cells[0].firstChild` for the anchor. Where do you need to access the anchor details *from*?
 If it's from an event handler attached to the anchor you'll already have a reference to that element available.

Comment: Question is not clear. `.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks everyone, after multiple tries, this worked for me:rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have such a table

```
<table id="table">
  <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>21</td><td>22</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then to access some specific cell content I would use the following approach:

```
  function getCellContent(x, y) {
    x = parseInt(x, 10);
    y = parseInt(y, 10);
    if(isNaN(x) || --x < 0 || isNaN(y) || --y < 0) {
      return;
    }
    var tE = document.getElementById('table');
    var rows = tE.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    if(!rows || y >= rows.length) {
      return;
    }
    var row = rows[y];
    var cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
    if(!cells || x >= cells.length) {
      return;
    }
    var cell = cells[x];
    return cell.innerHTML;
  }

  console.log(getCellContent(1, 2)); // "12"
```

Note, that `x`, `y` arguments are being started from "1". That's why I decrementing arguments. Three `return` statements are for bad params and out-of-range protections. So you'll get just `undefined` if something's not ok.

I also created a [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z12ka7?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the help but something else worked for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @jyotirmayaojha I see your `rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent` in the comments. It is the same approach but not generalized and with no protections. BUT! This may be important if you want to create reusable code: __(a)__ to provide a function and __(b)__ make it safe for calls with all types of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```js
var tableObj = document.getElementById("testTable");
var rows = tableObj.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i=0; i< rows.length ; i++){
  var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var j=0; j<cells.length ; j++) {
    console.log(cells[j].innerText);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="testTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```